# How do I bind Interface in Ninject only if it is not already bound?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

Is it possible to configure Ninject to not bind a dependency if it is already bound.

E.g.

If we load a module say called Client1 containing:

```
public class Client1Module:NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
         Bind<IService>.To<FancyService>()
    }
}
```

Then we load a module called Base containing

```
public class BaseModule:NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
          Bind<IService>.To<BasicService>()
    }
}
```

We would like to ensure that BasicService isn't bound and the system always uses FancyService. We won't know at design time whether FancyService exists. Client1 module is loaded if it is located.

I don't really want a bunch of repeitive boiler plate code around every injection etc. As there are 50-60 dependencies that all could be changed in Client modules.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any way to identify which implementation of `IService` is preferred? What if 3 are loaded? You could use reflection to get all types which implement `IService` very easily (this is how we do our registrations) but we use custom attributes to assign priorities or to allow/disallow duplicated

Comment: Basically we are creating a system that is bespoked on a per client basis but with a single code base (as forking per client was the most miserable nightmare). So each client may end up with an implementation of IService if there requirements are different. In most cases most people I hope would probably not need changes. So the aim was to load the few changes from the standard from a client DLL and then apply the standard ones if there was nothing client specific. I think it would be a case that there would only ever be the core implementation or the client/feature specific

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I assume I load the base Module first and then load the Client Module after I think I can just use

```
Rebind<IService>.To<FancyService>()
```

It seems to work

Answer (score 7):

You have to make sure BaseModule is loaded after Client1Module:

```
   public class BaseModule: NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            if (!Kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IService)).Any())
            {
                Bind<IService>().To<BasicService>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So I had would have to put the if around every single binding? That was my concern with that approach.

Comment: You could factor some logic into a custom NinjectModule class, but I think so.

Comment: Yeah I'd need to. I can see us ending up with hundreds of interfaces as the application grows and I will need to come up with some way of doing conditional binding if not bound type thing. Even if it was some way of adding binding to a list running through them and checking if they are bound and if not add them to the actual list to bind. However my Ninject skills are not good enough.